# mysql order items not working in my query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the code below, but my query does not order the items as expected.

My columns are declared as `DOUBLE`

[image]

Query:

```
Select VendorName, format(SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price),2) as Total_Purchase 
from purchases 
group by VendorName 
order by Total_Purchase desc;
```

Comment: You're ordering by a string (because the [Format function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) outputs a string). String ordering is different to numeric ordering. Order by `SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price)` instead - i.e. order by the actual numeric value, not the formatted-for-presentation version of it.

Comment: P.S. I'd argue that in most situations your SQL query should just output the raw number. Any presentational stuff such as adding commas etc should really be done by whatever tool / application is doing the final presentation of the data to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `format(SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price),2)` and `order by SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price) desc`:

```
Select VendorName, format(SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price),2) as Total_Purchase 
from purchases 
group by VendorName 
order by SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Format function returns a string hence the ordering is not as expected. You can use the round function to get the same effect without converting it into a string.

```
Select VendorName, ROUND(SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price),2) as Total_Purchase 
from purchases 
group by VendorName 
order by Total_Purchase desc;
```

Edit: If you really need the formatting, you could use something like this:

```
select VendorName, format(Total_Purchase_Int, 2) as Total_Purchase
from (
  Select VendorName, ROUND(SUM(Order_Quantity*Net_price),2) as 
  Total_Purchase_Int 
  from purchases 
  group by VendorName 
  order by Total_Purchase desc
) as temp_purchase_table;
```

Comment: except it won't add the commas, which presumably the OP wanted

Comment: Yeah. We can get the formatting too by wrapping this up in a select query if required.